# Unwanted calls to the server in my View Results Tree

Tags: jmeter-5.0

I am making a simple GET call to the server (wikipedia). However, in the View Results tree, I see 4  extra calls. How can I eliminate them ? Only the first call is valid. The other 4 are garbage calls that i dont want to see in my view results tree.

[image]